# How does damage resistance work?

Tags: fallout-4

Armor provides a certain amount of damage resistance against different types of damage. This value is obviously not just substracted from the damage, but I don't see any information in the game on how it actually works.

What is the formula for the reduction of damage base on the damage resistance of your armor?

Comment: A quick Google search brings up http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Damage_Resistance which also includes a section on Fallout 4

Answer (score 4):

Damage resistance in Fallout 4 is calculated differently from in the other Fallout games. Instead of being a straight calculation, the damage resistance is based not just on the resistance value, but also on the incoming damage. When your damage resistance is precisely equal to the incoming damage, the damage will be cut in half. Any damage resistance above that shows diminishing returns. The approximate formula, taken from [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Damage_Resistance), is [image]

Comment: It's worth noting that Damage effects, affect damage in different ways. For example Bleed damage doesn't appear to be affected by any resistance. This [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3tjngh/useful_info_inside_on_games_mechanics_after_a_lot/) goes into great depth on the subject.