# WoW attack speed calculation

Tags: world-of-warcraft-classic

Reading up on attack speed calculations for World of Warcraft I noticed that the formula for attack speed is:

> Attack_speed = "current attack speed" / (("Percent increase or
>   decrease" / 100) + 1 )

So with a weapon of speed 1.8 and activating a 40% attack speed buff for example we would have:

> Attack_speed = 1.8 / ( (40 / 100) + 1 ) = 1.2857

So I am just wondering why is there a +1 in the formula. Logically I would assume that one would calculate the attack speed like this:

> Attack_speed = 1.8 - (1.8 * (40 / 100)) = 1.08

Which is just subtracting the 40% of 1.8 from 1.8. Is this just by design or is there some logic to this?

Comment: I haven't got time for an answer that will do this justice (I'll try to post later) but for now, imagine having +100% attack speed and apply your formulas.

Comment: Looking forward to that answer. :)

Comment: Where did you get your formula? And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Formula is from https://wow.gamepedia.com/Attack_speed. My question is stated. I am just wondering why is it not calculated like one would usually calculate percentage increases/decreases.

Comment: Sorry, we don't allow questions asking why something in a game is the way it is. Only the developers can answer that.

Comment: @Wrigglenite calculating speed/attack/etc. is an important part of [theorycrafting](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12244/is-theorycrafting-off-topic).

Comment: @dly But this question is asking for the reasons why this specific formula was used. That is not theorycrafting, and nobody can answer that other than the developers.

Comment: @Wrigglenite It's asking for the logic behind it, which can be a theorized version of in-game logic as well. It's similar to questions like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38485/how-does-multiplying-damage-work-in-skyrim) and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244048/how-does-damage-resistance-work).

Comment: @Joachim I don't see the resemblance. This question is asking "Here's the formula. Why this formula?" while the other two are asking "What is the formula?". Regardless, we can't possibly answer this question other than guessing.

Comment: @Wrigglenite My point is that we've had questions asking about the calculations behind game mechanics. And I think this has already been answered satisfactorily (it was quite clear the integer was part of the formula to limit the outcome).

Comment: @Joachim But as I've said, this question is not about the formula itself, is about the reasoning behind a certain decision made by the developers, which we cannot answer in any way other than guessing. Formulae can be figured out by playing the game, the developers' thinking cannot. That is the difference between this question and the other two.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Now I'm beginning to doubt it as well.. I think you're right - I realize now I based my assessment on my initial guess of and the answer itself, but the germaneness of a question doesn't depend on the (potential) answer. Vote retracted.

Comment: (Which I can't for some reason..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why was that formula used?

It ensures the result is sensible in all situations, no matter how large your attack speed bonus becomes, and without requiring a cap on possible attack speed bonus.

Consider your proposed formula - `"current attack speed" - ("current attack speed" * ("attack speed bonus" / 100))` - with an attack speed bonus of 100% (credit to Studoku in the comments):

```
1.8 - (1.8 * (100 / 100)) = 1.8 - (1.8 * 1) = 1.8 - 1.8 = 0
```

What would an attack speed of 0 mean in practical terms? How many times per second would you expect to be attacking with that attack speed?

You get a similar issue with any bonus exceeding 100%, where your attack speed is now negative. What would that mean?

#### Why is the + 1 included?

It avoids incorrect - or even unknown - results in certain situations (i.e. with specific attack speed increases). Consider the following two examples *without* the `+ 1` in the formula used.

Attack speed bonus of 0%:

```
1.8 / (0 / 100) = 1.8 / 0 = ???
```

Attack speed bonus of 100%:

```
1.8 / (100 / 100) = 1.8 / 1 = 1.8
```

Comment: So it is 'by design'. One can't think of it like just a mathematical percentage increase/reduction.